# java error in logger code

Tags: java, logging

I found this code in the net and studying it to better understand how the logging works but it has an error in one particlar line and I can't seem to fix it.

```
static public void setup() throws IOException {

  System.out.println("MyLogger");
  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

    // suppress the logging output to the console
    Logger rootLogger = Logger.*getLogger*("");   <---- ERROR (getLogger cannot be resolved or is not a field)
    Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();
    if (handlers[0] instanceof ConsoleHandler) {
      rootLogger.removeHandler(handlers[0]);
    }

    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    fileTxt = new FileHandler("Logging.txt");
    fileHTML = new FileHandler("Logging.html");

    // create a TXT formatter
    formatterTxt = new SimpleFormatter();
    fileTxt.setFormatter(formatterTxt);
    logger.addHandler(fileTxt);

    // create an HTML formatter
    formatterHTML = new MyHtmlFormatter();
    fileHTML.setFormatter(formatterHTML);
    logger.addHandler(fileHTML);
  }

}
```

Anyone have any idea why? ty in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is [`java.util.logging.Logger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html), I strongly suspect you have imported some other `Logger`

```
 // Something like this
 java.util.logging.Logger rootLogger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("");
```